# Type conversion during function call in python

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

In the example below I'm passing float value to a function accepting and int argument (using type hints). Looks like the value read into the function arg is a float nonetheless (was expecting int(11.2) * 10 = 110 instead of 112)

Why is this the case?

```
def f(n:int):
    return n*10
l = [11.2, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]
mfunc = map(f,l)
print(list(mfunc))
```

> Result: [112.0, 22.0, 33.0, 44.0]
>
> ** Process exited - Return Code: 0 ** Press Enter to exit terminal

Comment: As you said, it's just a type **hint**.  It tells the user that it expects to get an integer, but no enforcement action will be taken.

Comment: As @MechanicPig rightly said no implicit casting goes on when you used type hint. So you will have to do your casting explicitly. ```return int(n) * 10```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mechanic Pig said `n:int` in function signature is just a hint for developer and its not converts to int.

So you cast to int

```
def foo(n: int):
  if type(n) is float:
      n = int(n)
  return n * 10
```

Or you can use assert to raise error if `n` is not `int`

```
def foo(n: int):
    assert type(n) == int, "must be int"
    return n * 10
```

or

```
def foo(n: int):
    if type(n) is not int:
        raise Exception(f"Must by int instead of {type(n).__name__}")
    return n * 10
```

Hints more useful when you use IDE that support it.

Here  `-> int:` describes what type function returns

```
def foo(n: int) -> int:
    return n * 10
```